# when using pip install lanms getting this error FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, windows, pip, anaconda

I am using windows 10. when I am running `pip install lanms` getting following error:

```
Collecting lanms
  Downloading lanms-1.0.2.tar.gz (973 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 973.4/973.4 kB 6.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\thitesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a3zari9_\lanms_122d99fe74f547e5b860088ca7ae5f8f\setup.py", line 27, in <module>
          if subprocess.call(['make', '--always-make','-C', BASE_DIR]) != 0:
        File "C:\Users\thitesh\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 349, in call
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
        File "C:\Users\thitesh\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Users\thitesh\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: You seem to be missing make, do you have standard build tools installed? (compiler, build systems, etc)

Comment: installed make using `winget install GnuWin32.Make`

Comment: After installing `make` also getting same error.

Comment: is make in your path? did you check if make actually works?

Comment: Please tell how to check

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still facing an issue with this...I was able to use lanms in the following way:

1. Download lanms from github ([link](https://github.com/argman/EAST))
2. Follow the steps mentioned here ([link](https://github.com/argman/EAST/issues/120))

this worked for me successfully! Now you can import the project in your python project.